# 3D animation between layouts like the lock screen in jelly bean

Tags: android, animation, layout, view, 3d

So basically I'm trying to replicate this. It will be used like a view flipper. I haven't had much experience in doing this sort of stuff in android yet so any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, what are you going to achieve, but I would start with such lecture: [Android flip 3D animation](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html). It's quite easy to replace views in the middle of such animation. You may consider writing your own container, if the ViewFlipper is not enough.
If the view is too complex for Android to handle, or your animation is intended to be more interesting than simple flip/scale/move, then you may consider using OpenGL and shaders. Simply draw your views to bitmaps, pass it to OpenGL and do whatever you want to do with them.

Comment: The idea is to have each panel contain a view or any layout and have the user swipe left and right to switch between them using the 3d effect above. I've tried to find samples of this but most don't achieve the above.